# Парсер на Jquery. Поиск конкретного элемента внутри всех найденных

Tags: jquery, xml, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.
Делаю парсер на jquery, но никак не пойму, как мне из нескольких найденных элементов с одинаковым тегом выделить именно нужный?
Поиск осуществляю так:

```
$(this).find("link_fajla_org").text()
```

Так вот в xml-документе объектов с именем `link_fajla_org` у каждого блока несколько. Как мне выделить нужный? Вот часть xml:

```
<fail>
  <tip_fajla>план первого этажа в зеркальном отображении</tip_fajla>
  <type_nr>6</type_nr>
  <link_fajla>111</link_fajla>
</fail>
<fail>
  <link_fajla_org>222</link_fajla_org>
  <type_nr>18</type_nr>
  <link_fajla>333</link_fajla>
  <tip_fajla>визуализация спереди большая</tip_fajla>
</fail>
```

Как, например, мне вытащить `link_fajla`, у которого `type_nr=6`?

Comment: Может, вам стоит найти все типы фэйлов с нужным значением, а затем перейти к линку на фэйл с тем же родителем?

Comment: А как это сделать, подскажите?

Comment: Я больше по XQuery, там можно так (или около того): data(/fail[data(type_nr)=6]/link_fajla_org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно так?

```
$(this).find("type_nr").each(function(i,elem) {
    if($(this).text() == 6) {
           var text = $(this).parent().find("link_fajla").text()
           alert(text);
        }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8pzL0nt5/

Comment: Да, вроде то, что нужно. Но вот к моему коду что-то не могу приспособить. Он возвращает [objectOblect] либо то, что переменная text не определена.

$find.find("proekt").each(function () {

        $(".main").append('<div class="book"><div class="title"><strong>' + $(this).find("nazwanie_proekta").text() + '</strong></div><div class="foto"><a href=""><img src="' + text + '"></a></div></div>');
        $(".book").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}

Comment: text определена в функции, которая вызывается для каждого элемента. Снаружи ее нет.

Comment: А как же мне ее прилепить?

Comment: Например, не вызывать функцию для всех найденных, а выполнить нужное действие для первого из них.